# ¿Cómo desplegar el segundo select de forma dínamica dependiendo del primero en el admin de Django 4.2?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Cómo puedo resolver este problema en el admin de Django 4.2:

Al momento de yo querer ingresar ya sea un nuevo Código Postal o un nuevo Asentamiento desde el admin de mi proyecto, que cuando seleccione un estado me cargue o arroje al segundo select los municipios que corresponden a ese estado que yo seleccioné y cambien de forma dinámica cuando seleccione otro estado.

Estoy trabajando con las entidades federativas de la República Mexicana, la app de Django se llama estado y tengo lo siguiente:

en el archivo models.py tengo esto:

```
from django.db import models


class Estado(models.Model):
    abreviatura = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    estado = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Estados"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.estado}"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.estado


class Municipio(models.Model):
    municipio = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cabecera = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    estado = models.ForeignKey(Estado, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Municipios"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.municipio}"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.municipio


class CodigoPostal(models.Model):
    codigo_postal = models.CharField(max_length=5, unique=True)
    estado = models.ForeignKey(Estado, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    municipio = models.ForeignKey(Municipio, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Códigos Postales"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.codigo_postal}"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.codigo_postal


class Asentamiento(models.Model):
    asentamiento = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tipo_asentamiento = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    zona = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    estado = models.ForeignKey(Estado, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    municipio = models.ForeignKey(Municipio, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    codigo_postal = models.ForeignKey(CodigoPostal, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Localidades"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.asentamiento}"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.asentamiento
```

en el archivo admin.py tengo esto:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Estado, Municipio, CodigoPostal, Asentamiento


@admin.register(Estado)
class TablaEstados(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'abreviatura', 'estado')


@admin.register(Municipio)
class TablaMunicipios(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('municipio', 'cabecera', "estado")


@admin.register(CodigoPostal)
class TablaCodigoPostal(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('codigo_postal', 'municipio', "estado")


@admin.register(Asentamiento)
class TablaAsentamiento(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('asentamiento', 'tipo_asentamiento', "zona", "municipio", "estado", "codigo_postal")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]